# Reaching Definitions using LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I am trying to implement the naive implementation of Reaching Definitions. However, I am having trouble navigating through the LLVM framework. I am thinking of figuring out how to obtain the GEN set for a basic block first and then going for KILL sets (The same way as done in the naive algorithm).

Any guidance regarding the matter is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe it would be better to ask this question in http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @PhillipKinkade please flag questions for migrations rather than suggesting reposting.  Since this question now has an answer, if it *is* appropriate on P.SE, to keep the answers together this means that this question needs to be migrated, duped, and merged (which takes a bit of mod work).

Answer (score 2):

Reaching definitions analysis does not really apply to SSA-form languages such as LLVM IR, because there's never any re-definition (or re-assignment) of a variable that was already defined earlier.

Comment: Say you have an instruction %i = alloca i32  and then followed by two store instructions store 0 , i32* i and store 2 , i32* i the last store is a redefinition of the previous store if I am not wrong?

Comment: @lava_07 Reaching definitions classically refers to *variables*, e.g. the `%i` in your example, and that concept is not applicable in SSA. The whole point of reaching definitions to start with is to know what uses what, and you don't need that here (though LLVM IR does have a similar concept with *dominance* - when you refer to a value, its definition must dominate the current BB/phi node clause). In any case, your example is actually [memory dependence](https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#memdep-memory-dependence-analysis), which is different - in particular because memory can be aliased.